# node.js - how to insert values from a json array into a sql database

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have incoming json structure like

```
{
    "type":1,
    "location":[
        {"lattitude":"0", "longitude":"0"},
        {"lattitude":"0", "longitude":"0"},
        {"lattitude":"0", "longitude":"0"}]
}
```

I need to insert this into a database like

```
|------|-----------|-----------|
| type | lattitude | longitude |
|------|-----------|-----------|
| 1    | 0         | 0         |
|------|-----------|-----------|
| 1    | 0         | 0         |
|------|-----------|-----------|
| 1    | 0         | 0         |
|------|-----------|-----------|
```

how do I parse the json and build an sql query?

Comment: Is your json structure constant or varying ? Postgres has json related functions which can work on json directly within a Postgres function call and constructing a query won't be needed.

Comment: @KaushikNayak it's always in this form

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Postgres solution, you may do

```
--INSERT INTO yourtab( type,lattitude,longitude)

select jsoncol->>'type' , j->>'lattitude'
             j->>'longitude'
 from
 ( values (:yourjsonstr :: jsonb ) ) as t(jsoncol) cross join 
          lateral jsonb_array_elements(jsoncol->'location')
                                   as j;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5f8fe343adf59e66eae2c9e7084163af)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json-sql`

Example:

```
var sql = jsonSql.build({
    type: 'insert',
    table: 'users',
    values: {
        name: 'John',
        lastname: 'Snow',
        age: 24,
        gender: 'male'
    }
});

sql.query
// insert into users (name, lastname, age, gender) values ($p1, $p2, 24, $p3);

sql.values
// { p1: 'John', p2: 'Snow', p3: 'male' }
```

See the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-sql

Comment: is this faster than inserting multirow values?

Comment: @niga I don't think there will be a large difference